# Text appears behind images (undesirable), but gets in its place when refreshed

Tags: html, css

I'm (finally) starting to learn how to write web pages. I have this little issue:

I'm putting a `<div>` with some images (it's a simple slideshow, and it works great), and below it a paragraph inside another `<div>` (the relevant code is below). But when I open the page in the browser, *sometimes* the paragraph appears behind the images, but once I refresh the page, it appears on it's right place.

The *sometimes* is the thing that bothers me most. If it *always* appeared behind the immages, I'd know I was doing something wrong... but that's not the case... so, am I missing something?

So, the specific question is: How to ensure that the second `<div>` *always* appears below the first one?

The code:

**index.php**

```php
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts/script_main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainpanel">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <?php
                /*
                 This will simply add the images to the slideshow, and it works great
                 */
                $dir = "img/index";
                $files = scandir($dir);
                $i = 0;
                foreach($files as $img) {
                    if(substr($img, 0, 5) == "slide" && substr($img, -4) == ".jpg") {
                        $i++;
                        if($i == 1) {
                            echo "\n" . '<img alt="" class="active" src="' . $dir .'/' . $img . '" />';
                        } else {
                            echo "\n" . '<img alt="" src="' . $dir .'/' . $img . '" />';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>

        </div>
        <!-- 
             This is the place where the problem seems to be:
             This second div sometimes appears behind the first one.
          -->
        <div class="slideshow_text">
            <p>
                Suspendisse eu nibh ac ex interdum auctor. 
                Curabitur in nisi a libero tempor volutpat. 
                Praesent ornare tortor quis tempus aliquam.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**css/index.css**

```css
#mainpanel {
    min-height: 50em;
}

#mainpanel #slideshow {
    min-height: 430px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#mainpanel #slideshow img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 2em;
    max-width: 80%;
    width: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}

#mainpanel #slideshow img.active {
    z-index: 10;
}

#mainpanel #slideshow img.last-active {
    z-index: 9;
}

#mainpanel .slideshow_text {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    clear:both;
}
```

**js/scripts/script_main.js** (Just in case the problem is here)

```js
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');

    if($active.length === 0) {
        $active = $('#slideshow img:last');
    }
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow img:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
         .addClass('active')
         .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
             $active.removeClass('active last-active'); 
         });
}

$(function() {
   setInterval('slideSwitch()', 5000) ;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $slideshow_height = $('#slideshow img:first').height();
    $('#slideshow').css('min-height', $slideshow_height);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var $slideshow_height = $('#slideshow img:first').height();
    $('#slideshow').css('min-height', $slideshow_height);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day :) I would suggest you to force your text element to be over slideshow elements with z-index, maybe you should try adding something like:

```
#mainpanel .slideshow_text {
    z-index: 12;
}
```

Comment: Hi... the problem is not wether the `<div>` with the text appears behind or over the `<div>` with the images... it should appear below

Comment: In this case I would also try to use this [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) hack for your #mainpanel #slideshow div. Maybe this is the consequence of offset positioning of slideshow elements.